# The header file of RWTexture2D

Tags: c++, directx

I got the error of identifier "RWTexture2D" is undefined but nowhere to find the hearder file of RWTexture2D. Does any body know that or any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RWTexture2D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a type you would use in your HLSL (shader) code, not in your C++ code.

Comment: Thank you! Things starts to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the type (like a template) in your shader/HLSL code. So something like this:

So this is wrong:

`RWTexture2D tex;`

But this is correct:

`RWTexture2D<float> tex;`

See the documentation for `[RWTexture2D][1]` HLSL type.